# Access to statistics and summary hazelcast instance

Tags: java, hazelcast

Is there a way to retrieve information about the statistics (eg, memory usage, free memory, etc.) hazelcast instance without using JMX?

Comment: Why don't you want to use JMX?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the man-center.
It's a war you have to deploy in your webserver, where hazelcast is running.
One configured and deployed you can check memory usage, data in the maps and run javascript at runtime.

See here:

http://docs.hazelcast.org/docs/latest/manual/html/managementcenter.html

Very useful!